# <SID> with foldexpr

Tags: vim

I am reading [Learn Vim Script the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) and hit something that confused me whilst doing the exercise to convert the folding functions to script local ones.

I tried to go this:

```
setlocal foldexpr=<SID>GetPotionFold(v:lnum)
```

and renamed all the functions to start with `s:`

To my surprise this didn't work and every line had a fold level of 0? It works if I put `GetPotionFold` into the global scope. Do you have to use a globally scoped function when assigning it to a option? Why?

Comment: Steve Losh casually writes, ["We defined our helper functions as global functions, but that's not a good idea. Change them to be script-local functions."](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/49.html#exercises) Too bad this is an impossible task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<SID>`  can be used in a mapping or menu, unfortunately not in an option. (This is a shortcoming in the implementation.)

You'd either have to translate it into the actual `<SNR>NNN_` prefix (there's an `s:SID()` example function at `:help <SID>`), or use a different scope that is accessible from outside the script that defines the function. It's commendable that you want to avoid clobbering the global function namespace, as this is prone to name clashes.

A nice trick is using the *autoload* function prefix; it doesn't just work in autoload scripts, but can also be used elsewhere, e.g. in plugin scripts. Just prepend the script's name, and you'll have a function that can be invoked from anywhere, but scoped to the script's name:

```
:function! MyScriptName#GetPotionFold(lnum)
    ...
:setlocal foldexpr=MyScriptName#GetPotionFold(v:lnum)
```

Comment: Ahh good, I was worried I had missed something in the book! Thank you!

Comment: @Lerp This is a good illustration that there are no local functions in VimL. (If you say about anonymous functions here I can say that until my [extended-funcref](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/vim_dev/zXO2mwwDwbM) branch is merged they are just global functions with weird names like `123`.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer, you could define the function `s:SID()` to determine the script number as in the help documentation and then use `execute` to set the fold expression as following:

`exe "setlocal foldexpr=<SNR>" . s:SID() . "_GetPotionFold(v:lnum)"`